# Scheduled Android repeating notifications are sometimes disappearing on app restart

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, notifications, alarmmanager

In my Xamarin Forms project I implemented local notifications for iOS and Android.

iOS notifications work as expected, scheduled repeating notifications are still scheduled after app restart and after device reboot.

On Android though notifications sometimes disappear after app restart, sometimes not. I would expect scheduled repeating notifications to not be dropped from the notification queue and Android to handle that.

This is how I schedule my notifications :

```
var intent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(AndroidNotificationBroadcastReceiver));
var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Application.Context, int.Parse(id), intent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);
var alarmManager = Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService) as AlarmManager;
alarmManager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, triggerTimeMilliSeconds, triggerIntervalMilliSeconds, pendingIntent);
```

And this is how I check which notifications are scheduled:

```
var alarmIntent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(AndroidNotificationBroadcastReceiver));
return Enumerable
    .Range(0, _maxNotifications)
    .Where(index => PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Application.Context, index, alarmIntent, PendingIntentFlags.NoCreate) != null)
```

Notification Ids go from 0 to 63 (_maxNotifications is 64)

It works, notifications are scheduled and I can receive them, and most of the time when I restart the app the notifications are still scheduled, but sometimes they are gone.
What could be the problem?

Edit: It's not about rebooting the device, it's about just restarting the app.
`triggerIntervalMilliSeconds` is days or weeks on release, for testing purposes 1 or 2 minutes
`setExactAndAllowWhileIdle` is not an option, because we need repeating notifications

To clarify : When I open my app and schedule a repeating notification for a certain date and time I will receive that notification. And I will also receive repeats of that notification in the interval I set. I can check if there are scheduled notifications with the second code I posted. This would return an Enumerable with all scheduled notification ids. Now when I close my app and reopen it, the second code MOST OF THE TIME will return an Enumerable with all scheduled notification ids as before, but SOMETIMES this second code will return an empty Enumerable, indicating that the scheduled repeating notification was somehow removed.

Comment: It's not about rebooting the device, it's about just restarting the app. I know I have to use a BroadcastReceiver to reschedule notifications after boot, but I would not expect to have to reschedule them after app restart. And sometimes I don't. Sometimes I do.

Comment: I'd expect the behaivour for such notifications would be same as for push notifications: by design on android after you force quit app notifications are disabled until you relaunch app.

Comment: I would not expect that, when I schedule a notification to e.g. fire each Sunday at 5PM I expect to receive it even when my app is not started. That's what notifications are for right? To indicate to the user something has happened without him having the app open all the time. And as I said, it works ... most of the time.

Comment: What's the value of the `triggerIntervalMilliSeconds`? According to the official document, a short time repeating time AlarmManager recommend to use the `setInexactRepeating`. In addition, do you mean the notification can work well sometimes?

Comment: Furthermore, what does `sometimes disappearing ` mean? The notification never shows? Or it shows a few times but not on time?

Comment: Made some edits to my post to clarify things.

Comment: It's strange, maybe the variable `_maxNotifications` has been recycled when the app restart sometime? You can try to set a constant such as `Range(0, 63)`.